# How to fix this error with impressionist gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Hi i got error with impressionist gem. i use Rails 5.2.4.4

i did these steps :

gem 'impressionist'

then bundle install

then rails g impressionist and bundle install

Then next step :

```
in my blogs_controllers

class BlogsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authorize_admin, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]
    before_action :set_blog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  impressionist :actions => [:show, :index]

  def index
    @categories = Category.all

    cate = params[:cate]

    if !cate.nil?
        @blogs = Blog.where(:category_id => cate)
    else
        @blogs = Blog.all
    end
  end

  def show
    impressionist(@blog)
  end

  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)

    if @blog.save
        redirect_to blog_path(@blog), notice: "Successfully Created"
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @blog.slug = nil
    if @blog.update(blog_params)
    redirect_to blog_path(@blog), notice: "Successfully Update"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @blog.destroy
    redirect_to blogs_path
  end

  private

    def set_blog
      @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
      
    end

  def blog_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :body, :image, :category_id)
  end

  def authorize_admin
    return unless !current_user.admin?
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

in blog model

is_impressionable

in blog show

```
<%= @blog.impressionist_count(:filter=>:ip_address) %>
```

And i got this error :

NameError in BlogsController#show

uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::ParameterFilter
Extracted source (around line #80):

```
        # If the constant was actually loaded, something else went wrong?
        raise(e) if from_mod.const_defined?(const_name)
        CoreExt::ActiveSupport.without_bootsnap_cache { super }
      end

      # Signature has changed a few times over the years; easiest to not
```

Comment: paste your full controller file

Comment: please take a look on my new update! thanks

Comment: what exact rails version you use?

Comment: ah sorry i use Rails 5.2.4.4

Comment: this class is available since Rails 6 - https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveSupport/ParameterFilter/CompiledFilter so you need upgrade your rails version firstly to use it

Comment: Downgrade impressionist gem version